# How to read the data from the json file in PHP

Tags: php, json

How can I read the data from JSON File in PHP? I know there are many questions similar to this but my problem is different. In JSON File key and values are changing every week. How can get the value of key in a variable in php.

1st week

```
{
    "4.0.0": "http://127.0.0.1/updates/example/server/4.0.0.zip"
}
```

2nd week

```
{
    "4.0.1": "http://127.0.0.1/updates/example/server/4.0.1.zip"
}
```

3rd week

```
{
    "4.0.2": "http://127.0.0.1/updates/example/server/4.0.2.zip"
}
```

Actually, I want to check if there is a new version available or not?

Comment: What is the tag that encloses the version number and link information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json = file_get_contents('FILE');
$object = json_decode($json, true);

$version = array_keys($object)[0];
```

Comment: is this worse question?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand what you mean with that

Comment: I can't help you if you just say "not working" is there an error? Or what effect does it have?

Comment: `array_keys` looks for an array. In this instance, because the JSON is a single object, it's being returned as an `stdClass object`. I think that's his error

Comment: @mbozwood can you please some answer?

Comment: Changed that @mbozwood

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9e232df016d8a5b6da3c7bc308aef34bd3e5e926

Comment: @Hitesh please accept Marvin's answer as the correct one. He has corrected it appropriately.

Comment: I edited the solution into my answer, to it does not get burried here

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = file_get_contents('http://127.0.0.1/updates/example/server/update.json');
$array = json_decode($str, true); 
$versions = array_keys((array)$array)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$key = key(json_decode($json));
```